# jQuery .offset() getting undefined for class `top` of var object

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, syntax

I'm working on the following code, and a bit stumped why I'm getting an error in my debugger.  apparently in the line that starts with `var skillsLimit = ...` the class `.top` of var `skillsOffset` is undefined.   Am I setting the var for `skillsOffset` incorrectly here?

```
// Set Pie graph to position fixed during a specified range
        var $window = $(window);
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        var pos = $window.scrollTop(); //position of the scrollbar
        var $this = $(this);

        $window.bind('scroll', function(){ //when the user is scrolling...
            var pos = $window.scrollTop(); //position of the scrollbar              
            var skillsOffset = $('#skills').offset();
            var skillsLimit = $('#skills').skillsOffset.top + $('#skills').outerHeight();
            if ( pos > skillsOffset ) {
                $('.chartwell-pies').css({ 'position' : 'fixed' });
            }               
        });
```

Comment: Just use `var skillsLimit = skillsOffset.top + ...` You have `skillsOffset` as a local variable, not an attribute of the jQuery object. And maybe `pos > skillsLimit`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `$('#skills')` from the assignment to `skillsLimit`, you've already got the object in the line above:

```
var pos = $window.scrollTop(); //position of the scrollbar              
var skillsOffset = $('#skills').offset();
var skillsLimit = skillsOffset.top + $('#skills').outerHeight();
```